# Mdx Median query

Tags: ssas, mdx, median

Could really use a hand from someone on this mdx query. I am trying to produce a rolling median for the last 365 days on per user and per day basis. I need the median to be the median per user response days. It seems like a simple computation but I cannot see how to get it to work with the crossjoin in the mix. Any help would be so very appreciated! If you even have a suggestion on a direction to attack this from that would be great.

```
SET [2Years] AS
'{[FirstOrderDate].[Full Date].&[2010-01-15T00:00:00]:[FirstOrderDate].[Full Date].[2012-08-20T00:00:00]}'

MEMBER [Measures].[2YearMedianLag]
AS
median({[FirstOrderDate].[Full Date].currentmember.lag(365):[FirstOrderDate].[FullDate].currentmember} , [Measures].[Response Days])

SELECT {[Measures].[Response Days], [Measures].[MedianLag]} ON 0,
NonEmpty(crossjoin( [days],
[User].[User ID].children),[Measures].[Response Days]) ON 1
FROM [UserRevenue]
```

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

EDIT:

```
SampleData (UserName varchar(100) null, FirstOrderDate Datetime null, ResponseDays int null)
('Jim', '2001-01-03', 10)
('Fred', '2001-01-03', 80)
('Frank', '2001-01-04', 30)
('Sally', '2001-01-05', 18)
('Joan', '2001-01-06', 26)
('Bill', '2001-01-06', 15)
('Ted', '2001-01-08', 29)
('Sam', '2001-01-10', 9)
('Jane', '2001-01-17', 200)

SampleOutput (FirstOrderDate datetime null, MedianResponseDays int null)
('2001-01-03', 45)
('2001-01-04', 30)
('2001-01-05', 24)
('2001-01-06', 22)
('2001-01-07', 22)
('2001-01-08', 26)
('2001-01-09', 26)
('2001-01-10', 22)
('2001-01-11', 22)
('2001-01-12', 22)
('2001-01-13', 22)
('2001-01-14', 22)
('2001-01-15', 22)
('2001-01-16', 22)
('2001-01-17', 26)
```

Comment: Could you explain the ``MedianResponseDays`` for these dates: ``2001-01-05``, ``2001-01-16`` and ``2001-01-17``?

Comment: http://www.mathsisfun.com/median.html

Comment: For ‘2001-01-05’ we have a sorted list of (10, 18, 30, 80) for the trailing 3 days. Because it is an even count of numbers, we have to take the two middle numbers and divide by 2. (18+30)/2=24 

For ‘2001-01-16’ we have a sorted list of (9,10,15,18,26,29,30,80) for the trailing 14 days. Because it is an even count of numbers, we have to take the two middle numbers and divide by 2. (18+26)/2=22

For ‘2001-01-17’ we have a sorted list of (9,10,15,18,26,29,30,80,200) for the trailing 15 days. Because it is an odd count of numbers, we can take the middle number. 26

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's tricky because you need to work with a different set of rolling dates per day on rows. Are you sure you want 365 for the lag? That gives you 1 year plus 1 day. Anyway, this technique uses an inline named set to create a named set for each combination of user/date and assigns it a unique number, then you can pull that named set back out again in a StrToSet function to match up with the current row's user and dates. This version factors in each individual user:

```
with 
set Users as [User].[User ID].Children
set UsersDates as NonEmpty((Users, [FirstOrderDate].[Full Date].children), [Measures].[Response Days])

set [Rolling Period] as 

    Generate(
       UsersDates,
          StrToSet(
        "{[FirstOrderDate].[Full Date].currentmember.lag(364): [FirstOrderDate].[Full Date].currentmember} as RP" + CStr(UsersDates.CurrentOrdinal)
          )
    )

member [Measures].[Median Lag] as 
median(
    StrToSet("RP" + 
    CStr(Rank(([User].[User ID].CurrentMember, [FirstOrderDate].[Full Date].CurrentMember), UsersDates)))
  , [Measures].[Response Days])

select
{
[measures].[Response Days]
, [measures].[Median Lag]
}

on columns,
UsersDates
on rows
from UserRevenue
```

UPDATE #1: This version ignores the individual user and instead uses the response for all users for the applicable set of dates:

```
 with 
    set Users as [User].[User ID].Children
    set Dates as NonEmpty([FirstOrderDate].[Full Date].children, [Measures].[Response Days])

    set [Rolling Period] as 

        Generate(
           Dates,
              StrToSet(
            "{[FirstOrderDate].[Full Date].currentmember.lag(364): [FirstOrderDate].[Full Date].currentmember} as RP" 
+ CStr(Dates.CurrentOrdinal)
              )
        )

    member [Measures].[Median Lag] as 
    median(
        StrToSet("RP" + 
        CStr(Rank([FirstOrderDate].[Full Date].CurrentMember, Dates)))
      , ([Measures].[Response Days], [User].[User ID].[All]))

    select
    {
    [measures].[Response Days]
    , [measures].[Median Lag]
    }

    on columns,
    (Users, Dates)
    on rows
    from UserRevenue
```

UPDATE #2: Third time's a charm? Here's a query that gets me the results in your sample output. The key is that the set needs to generate a tuple for each date/user combination for the current date and store that as an inline named set, one per possible date which is uniquely identified by rank. So the first date (1/3) is rank 1, second date (1/4) is rank 2 etc when you look at the list of dates on rows. The first date 1/3/2001 has two items in the set - one with Jim for 1/3 and one with Fred for 1/3. So in the median calculation, the response days for each item in the related set need to be used. Because 1/3 is rank 1 in the list dates, the set called RP1 is retrieved, combined with response days for the items in the set (Jim and Fred) and the median is calculated.  Then the next date, 1/4, contains three items - the same as for 1/3 but now also Frank for 1/4, so that requires a recalculation of the median and so on.

```
with 
    set Users as [User].[User ID].Children
    set Dates as [FirstOrderDate].[Full Date].children

    set [Rolling Period] as 
        Generate(
           Dates,
              StrToSet(
            "NonEmpty(({[FirstOrderDate].[Full Date].currentmember.lag(364): [FirstOrderDate].[Full Date].currentmember} 
            , Users), [Measures].[Response Days]) as RP" 
+ CStr(Dates.CurrentOrdinal)
              )
        )

    member [Measures].[Median Lag] as 

    median(
        StrToSet("RP" + 
        CStr(Rank([FirstOrderDate].[Full Date].CurrentMember, Dates)))
      , [Measures].[Response Days])


    select
    {[measures].[Median Lag]}

    on columns,

    Dates
    on rows
    from UserRevenue
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to review this Stacia. I really respect your work. I know I am not alone. 

I see what you mean by this is a tricky one. I couldn’t wrap my head around it so I appreciate you lending a hand. However, when I run the query, is it possible this is computing a median [response days] for each individual user for the trailing 364 days instead of all users for the trailing 364 days? [Median lag] equals the [Response Days]. 


UserID Date   Response Days Median lag
87921 1/7/2011 2439 2439
89390 1/7/2011 2405 2405
95330 1/21/2011 2333 2333
96260 1/20/2011 2319 2319

Comment: Sorry - based on your statement "I am trying to produce a rolling median for the last 365 days on per user and per day basis" I thought you meant you wanted to consider only the current user when evaluating the median across the set of dates. I've updated my answer with an alternate query that ignores the current user and only considers dates for the median. If I still don't have it correct, please clarify what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I’m sorry, I’m not doing a good job of describing this. However, I think this is very close. I cannot thank you enough.

Perhaps an example would describe this best assuming we only have data for 5 users.  (Jim,ResponseDays:10,FirstOrderDate:Jan03,MedianLag:10),(Fred,ResponseDays:20,FirstOrderDate:Jan03,MedianLag:15),(Frank,ResponseDays:30,FirstOrderDate:Jan04,MedianLag:20),(Sally,ResponseDays:18,FirstOrderDate:Jan-055,MedianLag:19),(Joan,ResponseDays:26,FirstOrderDate:Jan06,MedianLag:20)
The MedianLag is for each user for each day together going back 364 days

Comment: @Ryan Could you provide a sample of data and the result you are expecting to have?

Comment: Yes, I tried to provide some sample data in the previous post where medianLag showed the output I'm looking for to @stacia, but I'm limited on characters. I will do a better job of getting some sample data to you shortly. Might have to split it between a couple posts. Thank you!

Comment: Here is some sample data: create table SampleData
(UserName varchar(100) null, FirstOrderDate Datetime null, ResponseDays int null) 
insert SampleData
values ('Jim', '2001-01-03', 10)
insert SampleData
values ('Fred', '2001-01-03', 80)
insert SampleData
values ('Frank', '2001-01-04', 30)
insert SampleData
values ('Sally', '2001-01-05', 18)
insert SampleData
values ('Joan', '2001-01-06', 26)
insert SampleData
values ('Bill', '2001-01-06', 15)
insert SampleData
values ('Ted', '2001-01-08', 29)
insert SampleData
values ('Sam', '2001-01-10', 9)
insert sampledata
values ('Jane', '2001-01-17', 200)

Comment: Sampleoutput part 1: create table SampleOutput
(FirstOrderDate datetime null, MedianResponseDays int null)
insert SampleOutput
values ('2001-01-03', 45)
insert SampleOutput
values ('2001-01-04', 30)
insert SampleOutput
values ('2001-01-05', 24)
insert SampleOutput
values ('2001-01-06', 22)
insert SampleOutput
values ('2001-01-07', 22)
insert SampleOutput
values ('2001-01-08', 26)
insert SampleOutput
values ('2001-01-09', 26)
insert SampleOutput
values ('2001-01-10', 22)
insert SampleOutput
values ('2001-01-11', 22)
insert SampleOutput
values ('2001-01-12', 22)

Comment: Sample output part2: insert SampleOutput
values ('2001-01-13', 22)
insert SampleOutput
values ('2001-01-14', 22)
insert SampleOutput
values ('2001-01-15', 22)
insert SampleOutput
values ('2001-01-16', 22)
insert SampleOutput
values ('2001-01-17', 26)

Comment: That helps immensely. I've revised the query accordingly.

Comment: Yes! this is it! Perfect! Thank you so much! This problem has vexed me for the past couple weeks and having a solution is immensely cathartic. I'm sorry I didn't provide a better example to begin with. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

The `MedianResponseDays`  measure iterates on the user to compute the median value of `Response Days` from a given date to the current date. I put the 365 days. on the rows.

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[MedianResponseDays] AS
    Median([User].[User ID].children * [FirstOrderDate].[FullDate].CurrentMember:[FirstOrderDate].[FullDate].DefaultMember, [Measures].[Response Days])
SELECT {[Measures].[MedianResponseDays]} ON 0,
NON EMPTY {[FirstOrderDate].[Full Date].currentmember.lag(364):[FirstOrderDate].[FullDate].currentmember} ON 1
FROM [UserRevenue]
```

Comment: Thank you for looking at this problem Benoit. If you hadn't helped me pull together a good sample/example of what I was looking for it likely would not have gotten solved.

Answer (score 0):

I have a fact table fct_line_details having two columns mtid, productivity

```
  mtid     productivity
  ----     ------------
  1        400
  1        200
  1        600
  2        700
  3        900
```

I want to calculate the median for each mtid in SSAS . (median for mtid 1=400 )